# NoMethodError in Teams#edit with undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this kind of question is answered many times on this forum. But I tried a lot on stackoverflow and Google but could not solve this problem.

In my project, I have team, user and team_user model which allow to create team and while creating new team, I can also add new users and team lead. Currently I am able to create team with users and team lead.There is many to many relationship between user and team with team_user is joining model.

*Problem*
When I click on edit, it throws  "**`NoMethodError in Teams`**" error with **`"model_name' for NilClass:Class"`**. "Edit" action is available in team controller and which has **`@team`** instance variable and it is used in _form.html.erb(edit). I tried in many ways but could not find solution.

*teams_controller.rb*

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authorize_admin!
    before_filter :set_form_variables, only: [:new, :index] # everywhere the form is displayed


    def index
      @teams = Team.all
      @team = Team.new
    end

    def new
      @team = Team.new
      @users = User.all
    end

    def edit
      @team = Team.find(param[:id])
    end

    def create
      @team = Team.new(params[:team])
      team_lead = User.find(params[:team_lead_id])
      @team.team_lead = team_lead
      if @team.save
        users = User.where(:id => params[:users])
        users.each {|user| @team.users << user}
        flash[:notice] = 'Team has been created'
        redirect_to teams_path
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Team not created'
        redirect_to teams_path
      end
    end

    private
      def set_form_variables
        @team = Team.new
        @users = User.all
      end

     def update
       puts "====================================="
        @team = Team.find(params[:id])
        if @team.update_attributes(params[:team])
          flash.notice = "Team #{@team.name} has been updated"
          redirect_to team_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

     def destroy
       @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
       @team.destroy
       redirect_to teams_path
     end
end
```

***_form.html.erb(edit)***

```
 <%= form_for @team do |f| %>

  <div style=" margin-top:10px">
    <label> Team Name </label>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>

  <label> Add Users </label>
  <%= select_tag "users[]", options_from_collection_for_select( @users, :id, :first_name),:style => "width:270px; height:35px", :id => "drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations",
     :multiple => true %>

   <label> Team Lead </label>
  <%= select_tag(:team_lead_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :first_name)) %>

  <div class=modal-footer>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <%= f.submit 'Create Team', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*_table.html(edit)*

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "team", :media => "all" %>
<table  id='example'  class=" table-boarder roler ">
  <thead style="background-color: #ffffff">
    <tr>
      <th >Team Id </th>
      <th> Team Name </th>
      <th>Team Lead </th>
      <th> Team users </th>
      <th> Created at </th>
      <th> Update at </th>
      <th> Action</th>
      <th> Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody class="table-hover">
      <% @teams.each do |teams| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= teams.id %></td>
          <td><%= teams.name %></td>
          <td><%= teams.team_lead_id %></td>
          <td> <% teams.users.each do |users| %>
          <%= users.first_name %>
          <% end %></td>
          <td><%= teams.created_at %></td>
          <td><%= teams.updated_at %></td>
           <td>
      <%= link_to 'edit',edit_team_path(teams), :class => 'btn-small btn-primary' %>
    </td>
    <td>
       **<%= link_to "delete", team_path(teams), :method => :delete, :class => 'btn-small btn-danger', :confirm => 'Are you sure to delete' %>**
    </td>
        </tr>
     <% end %>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Above is the table which has link for **`"delete".`**. I tried a lot with editing team but could not.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
@team = Team.find(param[:id])
```

needs to be

```
@team = Team.find(params[:id])
```

Note the extra **s** in params.

Comment: hi @femaref, thanks for catch. But still I am getting following error:- NoMethodError in Teams#edit with undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass. any Idea about it.

Comment: No. Please try and debug it yourself - somewhere, you are calling map on a nil variable, usually meaning the array or enumerable you were excepting to be there is actually nil. Most likely in the edit template. Those are pretty basic errors and usually point to missing nil checks or the like. You should be able to fix them yourself.